# Animation timing problems

Tags: python, pygame

## The problem

I have two images and I wish to display them both every half second.
I do this with timer, yet whenever the image pops in it looks really weird because it seems like the first image is shown then disappears so you see the background, then the other image is shown quickly and disappears and shows the background.

## The code

```
#Importing files/modules
import pygame
import random

#Colors

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
ORANGe = (255, 115, 0)
YELLOW = (242, 255, 0)
BROWN = (115, 87, 39)
PURPLE = ( 298, 0, 246)
GRAY = ( 168, 168, 168)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)
GROUND = (156,168,91)
pygame.init()

#Screen
screenx = 1000
screeny = 700
screentotal = [screenx,screeny]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screentotal)

#Caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Animation attempt one")

#Variables
x = 500
y = 1000
a = 0
b = 500

#Booleans
go = True
#Graphics
one = pygame.image.load("1.jpg").convert()
two = pygame.image.load("2.jpg").convert()
one = pygame.transform.scale(one,(200,200))
two = pygame.transform.scale(two,(200,200))
#Position
position = [0,0]
#Time management
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
animation_timer = pygame.time.Clock()
animation_time = 0

#MAIN LOOP _________________________________________________________

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(GREEN)
    if go:
        animation_timer.tick()
        animation_time += animation_timer.get_time()
        if animation_time < x and  animation_time > a:
            screen.blit(one,position)
            x += 1000
            a += 1000
        if animation_time < y and animation_time> b:
            screen.blit(two,position)
            y += 1000
            b += 1000






    #Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
#Quit
pygame.quit()
```

## What I tried

I tried slowing the animation down, by changing the animation only every 1 sec not half a second. That makes it look worse because you see the image for only a small amount of time and you see background even longer before second image. I have tried to lower frame rate, to no avail. Thank you for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your screen.fill before each animation update and not fill the screen every time the loop runs. If you do that, you will cover your loaded images right after they appear.